# GA4: The page view is available in the graph, but not in the table

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm having an issue where the view of some pages is not displayed in a table, but is visible on other charts. As a result, events and conversions related to viewing these pages do not work correctly. Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[GA4 Pages and screens report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKary.png)

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today and figured it out. This is a major UI bug where GA4 hides all rows with small totals on reports making the results of your reports look blank which actually the data is hidden. The error is caused by thresholding "feature" in GA4 which automatically hides rows in charts when they deem the row count is too low to hide people's identity. The threshold is under roughly 30 sessions which is particularly bad if you are testing new landing pages or have small website traffic. The only warning you get is a small icon beside the title of your report.

To solve it this first select the property in question, then select Admin, then Reporting Identity, then Show All and then
Device-based and then Save. The user count will be less accurate for large counts, but small user counts will not be hidden.

Here a video that explains this in much more detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZUvxKQGfuA

Hope this helps!